# How to go to next tab in windows GUI

Tags: windows, pywinauto, uipath

I am working on interacting with windows GUI, where in i am trying to move from one tab to another.

I Want to move to next tab i.e Authentication tab using pywinauto. I tried tabcontrol but it is not working for me. Below is the image for reference.

Refering to the image below. I want to go the next tab which is Authentication tab from networking tab.

Also, Suggest me which is the best tool to automate the scripts which involves interaction with windows application / GUI.

[image: Local Area Connection 2 Properties]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: This tab control should be automatable using pywinauto (even with legacy "win32" backend). Which code doesn't work for you? Please post more details. I have no much time to write full example for you.

Answer (score -1):

[image: IE Option]

You can send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for each tab.